# Free images hosting with CDN

Tags: image, web, hyperlink, cloud, cdn

I am looking for free solution to image hosting with CDN. I got website on small paid hosting and there will be lot of image galleries which I would like to upload to some cloud like Google Drive and use cloud's CDN to link images on my web. Any recommendations for free solution ?

Answer (score 4):

CDN and cloud storage like Google Drive are two different things. 
A [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) can be defined as:

> A content delivery network or content distribution network is a
>   geographically distributed network of proxy servers and their data
>   centers. The goal is to provide high availability and high performance
>   by distributing the service spatially relative to end-users.

Where as cloud storage services provides highly available and secure storage space over the cloud. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327425/when-to-use-amazon-cloudfront-or-s3) which explains  the difference of these two in terms of AWS(CloudFront vs S3).

If your website traffic is moderate and you want to use free CDN, then you may signup for [AWS free tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/). The free tier gives you 50 GB Data Transfer Out and 2,000,000 HTTP and HTTPS Requests for Amazon CloudFront(AWS CDN) each month for one year.  Here's a tutorial for [getting started with AWS CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/deliver-content-faster/)

If you intended to use cloud storage services then also the free AWS tier provides you with 5 GB of space in [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) for 1 year.

Apart from AWS free tier you may also like to checkout free [Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/free/) or [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/free/). Levering these free tier resources it's even possible to host your current website on these platforms almost for free given the usage is within free tier limits.

Comment: CDN doesnt provide security as AWS provides?